# showing only first element from data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I have following code: [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ardinghelli-tgvwi)

In this scenario I am receiving some data from backend

```
    const attachments = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "someURLL_Name_1",
      link: "https://someURLL_Name_1",
      img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "someURLL_Name_2",
      link: "https://someURLL_Name_2",
      img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "someURL_Name_3",
      link: "https://someURLL_Name_3",
      img: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"
    }
     ];
```

I need to map them all and show only first element form my data, and show with numbers rest hided data.
In the end it should be like something like this:
`someURL_Name_1 https://someURLL_Name_1 +2 more`

I successfully mapped all my data and write little logic for `+ more`.

```
    <div className={Styles.attachments}>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return <Attachment key={item.id} data={item} image={item.img} />;
      })}

      {data.length > 1 && (
        <span className={Styles.more}>+{data.length - 1} more</span>
      )}
    </div>
```

Please help me to resolve a problem. Again, I want to show only first element , and then if there are another elements then I should hide them and show hide elements with numbers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't `map` over all entries then. The following will work :-

```
export const Attachments = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className={Styles.attachments}>
      {data[0] && (
        <Attachment key={data[0].id} data={data[0]} image={data[0].img} />
      )}

      {data.length > 1 && (
        <span className={Styles.more}>+{data.length - 1} more</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```